# How to compare two csv files with some matching conditions and write a new csv based on that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I am trying to merging two csv files into one with appropriate matching values. My idea was to scan two csv files and check if both column say `name` and `hotel_name` are same then add the rows in new csv file. So far I have tried this:

```
import csv

columns = [
    "query",
    "name",
    "hotel_name",
    "hotel_address",
    "hotel_star_ratings",
    "number_of_rooms",
    "number_of_reviews",
    "hotel_user_rating",
]


data = []

with open("source.csv", "r") as source, open("target.csv", "r") as target:
    source_reader = csv.DictReader(source)
    target_reader = csv.DictReader(target)

    for db_row in source_reader:
        for so_row in target_reader:
            if db_row["name"] == so_row["hotel_name"]:
                db_row["hotel_name"] = so_row["hotel_name"]
                db_row["hotel_address"] = so_row["hotel_address"]
                db_row["hotel_star_ratings"] = so_row["hotel_star_ratings"]
                db_row["number_of_rooms"] = so_row["number_of_rooms"]
                db_row["number_of_reviews"] = so_row["number_of_reviews"]
                db_row["hotel_user_rating"] = so_row["hotel_user_rating"]
        data.append(
            {
                "query": db_row["query"],
                "name": db_row["name"],
                "hotel_name": db_row["hotel_name"],
                "hotel_address": db_row["hotel_address"],
                "hotel_star_ratings": db_row["hotel_star_ratings"],
                "number_of_rooms": db_row["number_of_rooms"],
                "number_of_reviews": db_row["number_of_reviews"],
                "hotel_user_rating": db_row["hotel_user_rating"],
            }
        )

with open("output.csv", "w") as output:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=columns)
    writer.writeheader()

    writer.writerows(data)
```

But it didn't worked it is only outputs just one single row.

I am scanning those two csv files:

**source.csv**

```
query,name,hotel_name,hotel_address,hotel_star_ratings,number_of_rooms,number_of_reviews,hotel_user_rating
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Panský Pivovar
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Tacl
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Slavia Holešov
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Brusenka Restaurant a Pension
```

**target.csv**

```
hotel_name,hotel_address,hotel_star_ratings,number_of_rooms,number_of_reviews,hotel_user_rating
Hotel Panský Pivovar,"Masarykova 19, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",4,3,489,9.3
Pension Brusenka,"Brusné 3, Bystřice pod Hostýnem, 768 61, Česká republika",3b,12,556,9.2
Hotel Tacl,"Palackého 518, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",3,4,76,8.9
```

And my expected output is like this:

```
query,name,hotel_name,hotel_address,hotel_star_ratings,number_of_rooms,number_of_reviews,hotel_user_rating
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Panský Pivovar,Hotel Panský Pivovar,"Masarykova 19, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",4,3,489,9.3
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Tacl,Hotel Tacl,"Palackého 518, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",3,4,76,8.9
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Slavia Holešov,,,,,,
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Brusenka Restaurant a Pension,Pension Brusenka,"Brusné 3, Bystřice pod Hostýnem, 768 61, Česká republika",3b,12,556,9.2
```

Comment: Your example code won't even run -- you're looping over `db_reader`, which isn't defined. Additionally, you're looking for field `hotel_name` in the results from `source_reader`, which opens `source.csv`, but `source.csv` does not have a field named `hotel_name`.

Comment: I appologize for that it was bad from my side during copy pasting the code I have fixed it. But still it is adding only single row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another attempt:

```py
import csv

with open("source.csv", "r") as source, open("target.csv", "r") as target:
    source_reader = csv.DictReader(source)
    target_reader = csv.DictReader(target)

    dct1 = {}
    for line in source_reader:
        dct1[line["name"]] = line

    dct2 = {}
    for line in target_reader:
        dct2[line["hotel_name"]] = line

    out = []
    for name in dct1:
        if name in dct2:
            out.append({**dct1[name], **dct2[name]})
        else:
            out.append(dct1[name])

    print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "query": "ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",
        "name": "Hotel Panský Pivovar",
        "hotel_name": "Hotel Panský Pivovar",
        "hotel_address": "Masarykova 19, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",
        "hotel_star_ratings": "4",
        "number_of_rooms": "3",
        "number_of_reviews": "489",
        "hotel_user_rating": "9.3",
    },
    {
        "query": "ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",
        "name": "Hotel Tacl",
        "hotel_name": "Hotel Tacl",
        "hotel_address": "Palackého 518, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",
        "hotel_star_ratings": "3",
        "number_of_rooms": "4",
        "number_of_reviews": "76",
        "hotel_user_rating": "8.9",
    },
    {
        "query": "ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",
        "name": "Hotel Slavia Holešov",
        "hotel_name": None,
        "hotel_address": None,
        "hotel_star_ratings": None,
        "number_of_rooms": None,
        "number_of_reviews": None,
        "hotel_user_rating": None,
    },
    {
        "query": "ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",
        "name": "Brusenka Restaurant a Pension",
        "hotel_name": None,
        "hotel_address": None,
        "hotel_star_ratings": None,
        "number_of_rooms": None,
        "number_of_reviews": None,
        "hotel_user_rating": None,
    },
]
```

---

You can then save the list values (dicts) as new CSV file.

Answer (score 1):

This nested loop construct is your primary problem:

```
    for db_row in source_reader:
        for so_row in target_reader:
```

For ever row in `source_reader`, you're trying to loop over every row in `target_reader`...but both `source_reader` and `target_reader` are iterators, so after the first loop, `for so_row in target_reader` is a no-op: the iterator has been exhausted and the contents of the inner loop won't execute.

Instead of nesting these loops, first read one file, then the second, and then merge the results. Something like this:

```
import csv

fieldnames: list[str] = [
    "query",
    "hotel_name",
    "hotel_address",
    "hotel_star_ratings",
    "number_of_rooms",
    "number_of_reviews",
    "hotel_user_rating",
]

db: dict[str, dict] = {}

# Read 'target.csv' and populdate the 'db' dictionary
with open("target.csv", "r") as target:
    target_reader = csv.DictReader(target)
    for row in target_reader:
        db[row["hotel_name"]] = row

# Read 'source.csv' and update matching entries in
# 'db' with the value of the `query` column
with open("source.csv", "r") as source:
    source_reader = csv.DictReader(source)
    for row in source_reader:
        if row["name"] in db:
            db[row["name"]]["query"] = row["query"]

# Write out the reuslts
with open("output.csv", "w") as output:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(db.values())
```

Given your example input data, this code will produce:

```
query,hotel_name,hotel_address,hotel_star_ratings,number_of_rooms,number_of_reviews,hotel_user_rating
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Panský Pivovar,"Masarykova 19, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",4,3,489,9.3
,Pension Brusenka,"Brusné 3, Bystřice pod Hostýnem, 768 61, Česká republika",3b,12,556,9.2
"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Tacl,"Palackého 518, Holešov, 769 01, Česká republika",3,4,76,8.9
```

That doesn't match your desired output exactly -- I've omitted the duplicate hotel name column -- but you can always add it back if you need it.

Comment: it is working but skipping this row `"ubytování, Holešov, okres Kroměříž, Česká republika",Hotel Slavia Holešov`

Comment: No hotel by that name exists in `target.csv`. If you want the code to create an otherwise empty entry in this case, modify the second loop.